# ZipArchive::addFile(): No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having difficulties in solving my application's problem in making it possible to download a zipped file containing all the files.

The error is in line `$zip->addFile($a, '.zip');`.

```
    public function downloadZipFile(Solicitations $solicitations)
    {

        $anex = AnennexSolicitation::where('id_solicitation', $solicitation->id)->get();
        $zip_name = 'annex.zip';
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $public_dir = public_path() . "/storage/download";

        if ($zip->open($public_dir , ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
            foreach ($anex as $key => $a) {
                $a = $a->path; 
                $zip->addFile($a, '.zip'); // ZipArchive::addFile(): No such file or directory

            }
            $zip->close();
        }

        return response()->download(public_path($zip_name));
        
    }
```

Every time I do the error code it is on the same line.

Comment: Apparently whatever the value of `$a` is doesn't exist. Double-check what `$a` contains (`Log::info($a);` is a good way to save it to your logs in `storage/logs`), and make sure the file exists at that location.

Comment: ZipArchive::open wants a file path as first parameter, but your value looks rather like it was a directory? And are you really trying to add the file inside your ZIP under the name `.zip`? What sense does it even make to try and add files under the ever same, not-changing name, in a loop ...?